# How do I sprintf() in Perl?

Tags: perl, printf

Consider:

```
sprintf("%02d:%1d0", $tm[2], int($tm[1]/10)) if $rollup eq "600s";
```

It prints data every 10 minutes.

If I want to print data every 30 minutes, what is the correct way?
I tried:

```
 sprintf("%02d:%1d0", $tm[2], int($tm[3]/10)) if $rollup eq "600s";
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I worked with a contractor that would ask these sorts of questions. On his CV he stated he was the "subject matter expert" on Perl at a well known London banking company.

Answer (score 1):

All sprintf does is format the parameters - how frequently it runs is controlled by the if `$rollup  eq "600s"` part. It depends on how your $rollup is set/updated but assuming it's just an increasing number of seconds then something like `if $rollup eq "1800s"` might work

Comment: Hi, is this the correct?(30 mins)?                                           sprintf("%02d:%2d0", $tm[2], int($tm[1]/30) if $rollup eq "1800s";

Comment: What is stored in the $tm variable? if all you want to change is the frequency and not the text that's displayed then i'd probably keep the $tm stuff unchanged - it's impossible to tell without more details about the script.